# "Responses failed validation" for date field in SurveyMonkey v3 API

Tags: api, surveymonkey

I'm unable to create a successful payload to create a SurveyMonkey response using their v3 API
CreateResponse [POST] : https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/collectors//responses

**Relevant portion of my request**

```
...
"answers": [
   {
     "row_id": "2375981012",
      "text": "2019-10-11T12:56:55+00:00"          
 }
```

**Error Code :**

```
    "message": "Responses failed validation.",
        "id": "1025",
        "name": "Resource Conflict",
        "http_status_code": 409
```

The above format is as per [their documentation](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#data-types) . I have also tried dd/mm/yyyy and other formats, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

That response field requires only a date.

```
{
    sorting: null,
    family: "datetime",
    subtype: "date_only",
    required: {
        text: "This question requires an answer.",
        amount: "1",
        type: "exactly"
    },
    answers: {
        rows: [
            {
                visible: true,
                text: "Date / Time",
                position: 1,
                id: "2375981012"
            }
        ]
    },
    visible: true,
    href: "https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/271104269/pages/98907636/questions/359669069",
    headings: [
        {
            heading: "DOB"
        }
    ],
    position: 1,
    validation: {
        sum_text: "",
        min: null,
        text: "Please enter a valid date.",
        sum: null,
        max: null,
        type: "date_intl"
    },
    id: "359669069",
    forced_ranking: false
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. I'm probably missing something obvious, but I am still not able to tell what I am doing wrong. I see the same response details as you have posted but not sure what is wrong with my response. Can you please elaborate ?  I've even tried  what the comment within the code here says : https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/public_api_docs/blob/master/includes/_responses.md    "##Open Ended Multi/Numerical, Demographic, Datetime"

Comment: Can you provide the full payload and URL?

Comment: https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/collectors/247865208/responses . When I use this date format "17/10/2019 11:38 AM" or ""17/10/2019" (which is what the form expects), the survey response is valid, but survey monkey ignores the date so the response comes back as "questions": [] (empty array).

Comment: Payload : https://api.myjson.com/bins/1d4bqo  or http://myjson.com/1d4bqo